# Azure Cosmos DB - Access different data per user (SQL)

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-cosmosdb

I am new to web development, so the question might be trivial.

I have some physical devices, which will transmit humidity (and other stuff) to Azure Cosmos DB. I want users to be able to read their devices only(through a graph in a web app). All devices end up the the same collection.

I have set up a system in Azure in the following way:

> Device -> Azure IoT-Hub -> Azure functions -> Azure Cosmos DB.

The web app uses Azure B2C for users to be able to sign in, but how do i "assign" device-id´s to a user? I have read that it is possible to create access tokens with specific access to certain partition keys, but how do I store the information with access permissions for each user? Do I need a new database for storing this information only?

In the beginning it is fine if I have to grant permissions manually.

> General info:
>
> - The data in the Azure cosmos db are using device-id as the partition key.
> - Users can have more than one device.
> - The web app is running ASP.NET core (I am new here).
> - The web app requires log-in to be accessed.
> - I am coding in Visual Studio 2019, and have used the example with a build-in authorization.

Thank you for your help.

NOTE: It might be too much to ask for, but a general explanation together with a code example would be perfect for me :)

**UPDATE:**
I managed to fetch the email of the logged in user:

```
@using System.Security.Claims;  // for using ClaimsIdentity

// Get user information
var userEmailAddress = ((ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity).FindFirst("emails").Value;
```

My initial idea is then to have a database containing: "Email" and "accessible devices". I guess this has to be a separate database since i need the Time-To-Live parameter in cosmos db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I have been busy with other projects, but i finally came back to this issue.

So basically the reason why I wanted a separate database was because I need the TTL on the Azure Cosmos-DB, and I do not want to delete the user permissions.

It turns out that it is possible to overrule the database's default TTL by setting a "ttl" field in the document itself. Thereby it is possible to exclude documents from being deleted.

So the basic solution is:
Create a documents with a "ttl" parameter set to -1 to exclude it from being deleted. Then this document can contain information about which users have access to what.

Comment: This is not an answer to what you have asked. How to Access different data per user (SQL)? By setting the TTL to forever.
Also, your decision is very bad, because any user can read the data of the others.

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to achieve what you are looking for by using [Resource Tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/secure-access-to-data#resource-tokens).

As in this sample from the documentation, you can assign permissions by partition key:

```
//Create a user.
Database database = benchmark.client.GetDatabase("SalesDatabase");

User user = await database.CreateUserAsync("User 1");

// Create a permission on a container and specific partition key value
Container container = client.GetContainer("SalesDatabase", "OrdersContainer");
user.CreatePermissionAsync(
    new PermissionProperties(
        id: "permissionUser1Orders",
        permissionMode: PermissionMode.All,
        container: benchmark.container,
        resourcePartitionKey: new PartitionKey("012345")));
```

Comment: Yes, I am working through an example using this method. But how do I couple this to a B2C user? :)

Comment: Sorry, can’t help you with that

Comment: @silent Thanks a lot for the answer. Very helpful.
Would have been even better if you could specify the limitations of this method, i.e: what is the quota for number of users on CosmosDB